# Best HTML CSS color tool

Tags: html, colors

Does anyone have a good link to an HTML color chart or tool where I can click on exactly the color I want and it shows me the HTML color for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using Windows, here's a neat app I used to use often:

[Pixie](http://www.nattyware.com/pixie.php)

If you're on OS X and you're doing any sort of web coding without using coda, you should really try [coda](http://www.panic.com/coda/).

If you want some lame browser-based one, I guess [this](http://www.2createawebsite.com/build/hex-colors.html) would work.

Comment: this tool is perfect for what i need . . thanks !!!

Comment: I tried Pixie. It's brilliant! Small and simple, does exactly what it's intended to (pick colors on the screen in color picker or HTML hex code) and nothing more...! I specially liked that it is one single exe with size just 11.5KB!

Comment: It is a very excellent app. I haven't used windows since late 2006, and I'll never forget that application for it's handiness. Of course, OS X's color picker has the same functionality by default. It's the little things that I find myself appreciating the most.

Answer (score 5):

Just to keep you spoiled for choice...

[Color Scheme Designer 3](http://colorschemedesigner.com/)

Comment: this is very cool as well .. the thing i like about the top one is that i can point to some other section of a website and get that color without having to search through the css text

Comment: I always did like that as a feature myself, the other thing I loved about it was the shortcut keys. It made things extremely fast.

Answer (score 2):

Check out this HSL [color picker](http://www.workwithcolor.com/hsl-color-picker-01.htm) with css color notation output.

There are also color charts ordered by hue range and luminance with color codes.

Answer (score 0):

Many picture editors gives you this in the color selection dialog. If you also want to have a tool for creating buttons, icons, mouse pointers, etc. I will highly recommend this FREE app: [Greenfish Icon Editor Pro](http://greenfish.extra.hu/downloads.php). Despite the "Pro" in the name, the app is totaly free. Just a very optional function to donate money, but this is located in the Help menu, and no nag screen or anything is bothering you... 
This app supports 32 bit images and icons (gradient transparency).

Here is a good color chart with names and hex codes:
[DevGuru CSS color chart](http://www.devguru.com/technologies/css2/8025.asp)

In general, DevGuru has an excellent reference for web development, very tidy and easy to find what you are looking for.

[image: DevGuru.com]
<sub>(source: [devguru.com](http://devguru.com/images/dglogo.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer open-source, platform independent tools, I suggest you try out [colorPicker](http://colorpicker.riaforge.org/) which is a handy Adobe AIR utility that might serve your purpose. Some info about it from the site:

> colorPicker is a widget-like AIR
>   application that lets you either
>   choose a "web-safe" color from a color
>   grid or design a color using sliders
>   to adjust the red, green, and blue
>   values of the color. Once you have the
>   color you want, you can click on the
>   corresponding "Copy to Clipboard"
>   button to copy the hexidecimal color
>   code for the color and then paste it
>   into your HTML code or your IDE.
>   colorPicker also keeps a list of all
>   of the colors you've copied to the
>   clipboard during your session so that
>   you can review them and copy the hex
>   code to the clipboard again.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few cool web based tools for finding the right colours...  The first one on the list will even pick out a colour scheme based on an image you provide.

- http://kuler.adobe.com/
- http://www.colorcombos.com/combotester.html
- http://colorschemedesigner.com/

Answer (score 0):

The color you see is the color you have [www.color-tool.com](http://www.color-tool.com)

Comment: You should convert that URL to a link as a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Chrome [Eye Dropper For Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/hmdcmlfkchdmnmnmheododdhjedfccka)